# Block free-jqGrid from setting active class on table row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am using free-jqgrid 4.13.1 with `guiStyle: bootstrap`. In my jqgrid, it always adds the "active" class when the mouse moves over a row. I require special CSS rules to be unaffected while the user is using the grid. So how do I make my jqgrid not add the "active" class to each row as the user mouses over them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you use `guiStyle: "bootstrap"` to use Bootstrap CSS in free jqGrid (see [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#bootstrap)). In the case the class `"active"` will be added on hover the row.

You can use `hoverrows: false` to change the behavior.

**UPDATED:** The settings of `guiStyle: "bootstrap"` includes the usage of `table-hover` option. Thus `hoverrows: false` is recommended option in case of usage `guiStyle: "bootstrap"`. See [the part](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.4/js/grid.base.js#L670-L757) of free jqGrid code for details. On the other side if you want **to remove hover effect** from jqGrid then you should create custom Bootstrap GUI style without `table-hover` class and uses the style.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/Bootsrtap-noHover.html) demonstrates the approach. It defines `bootstrapNoHover` GUI style using

```
$.jgrid.guiStyles.bootstrapNoHover = {
    baseGuiStyle: "bootstrap",
    hTable: "table table-condensed table-bordered",
    subgrid: {
        legacyTable: "table table-condensed table-bordered"
    },
    grid: "table table-condensed table-bordered",
    gridFooter: "table table-condensed table-bordered"
};
```

and then uses `guiStyle: "bootstrapNoHover"` instead of guiStyle: "bootstrap".

Comment: I am using `guiStyle: 'bootstrap'` and added in `hoverrows: false` and am still experiencing very similar behavior. I can see it is no longer applying the `"active"` class, but there is still some color formatting occurring when mousing over the rows.

Comment: @CooperAtlas: See **UPDATED** part of my answer.